# If a group $G$ has the trivial center then $|Aut(G)|\geq |G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If a group $G$ has the trivial center then $|Aut(G)|\geq |G|$. Any suggestion?

Comment: try with internal automorphisms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** For $g\in G$ consider $x\mapsto g^{-1}\cdot x\cdot g$.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila Thanks. Following you hint, I can find $|G|$ maps in $Aut(G)$. Can you give me an example such that $|Aut(G)|>|G|$?

Comment: This map is a homomorphism $G\to Aut(G)$ whose kernel is $Z(G)$.

Comment: @lhf: Yes, and the assumption in the question states that the kernel is trivial so it's a monomorphism.

Comment: @Rose: Hm. Nothing comes to mind, sorry. I'll think about it some more...

Comment: For an example with $|{\rm Aut} G|>|G|$, take $G=A_4$, ${\rm Aut } G \cong S_4$. This works with 4 replaced by any $n \ge 4$, except for $n=6$ when $|{\rm Aut } A_6| = 2|S_6|$.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by a similar way as a special case of [N/C Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) that says $\text{Inn(G)}\lhd Aut(G)$ and $G/Z(G)\cong\text{Inn(G)}$.